# Equation for Sliding Collision of LineSegments

Tags: geometry, collision-detection

I need an equation to find point F.
Point A, B, and D are known. Point F is unknown. Point F is on line AB. Line AB is perpendicular to line DF. What is the equation for F?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want something computationally fast, since you mention 'collision', and this is Stack Overflow. First, a diagram:

[image: perpendicular intersection of AB and DF, with F the intersection point]

We want to calculate the components of **AF**, which we'll label **f** = q**i** + p**j**. AFD forms a triangle, so we can get the length of **f** from **AD**, which we'll label **d**. Let's mark lengths in italics versus vectors in bold:

*f* = *d* cos(θ).

But trig is computationally expensive. So let's use the fact that the vector dot product between **b** (AB) and **d** is:

**b** · **d** = *b* *d* cos(θ)

The angle is the same because AF and AB are on the same line. Substituting in for *d*cos(θ):

**b** · **d** = *b* *f*

*f* = (**b** · **d**) / *b*

Now we have *f*, but we want its components p and q. Calling the angle to the horizontal φ:

q = *f* cos(φ)

p = *f* sin(φ)

But again we're avoiding trig. We know that **f** is along **b**, so **f** = k**b**, and in fact using the unit vector in the direction of **b**:

**f** = *f* (**b**/*b*)

Substituting our expression for *f*:

**f** = [(**b** · **d**) / *b* ] (**b**/*b*)

= [(**b**/ *b*) · **d**  ] (**b**/*b*)

= [**b** · **d**] **b** / (*b*<sup>2</sup>)

Defining a factor k which is common to both components:

k = (b<sub>x</sub> d<sub>x</sub> + b<sub>y</sub> d<sub>y</sub>) /*b*<sup>2</sup>

By keeping the *b*<sup>2</sup> separate, we can avoid a square root operation to get the unit vector along **b**

Our components, then:

q = k b<sub>x</sub>

p = k b<sub>y</sub>

Finally, add back in the offset of point A.

Fx = Ax + q

Fy = Ay + p

So, the pseudo code:

```
var vbx = Bx - Ax;   //vector b x component
var vby = By - Ay;   //vector b y component
var dot = vbx*(Dx-Ax) + vby*(Dy-Ay); // dot product of b and d
var k = dot/(vbx*vbx + vby*vby);  // inverse of square of vector b length
var fx = Ax + k*vbx
var fy = Ay + k*vby
```

No square root calls, no trig, 8 additions/subtractions, 6 multiplications, 1 division. The only instabilities I can see are: divide by zero when A and B are at the same position, possible overflow calculating `dot` if AB is large and AD is large.

Answer (score 0):

First, find the slope of line AB with the point-slope formula using A and B's coordinates:
[Point Slope Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-slope_formula#Point.E2.80.93slope_form)

You can then find b to finished the equation for line AB:
`y = mx + b` where m is the slope you already found and b is the y-intercept that you just found.

The slope of line DF would be the negative reciprocal of the slope of line AB. Plug this into the equation:
y = mx + b where m is the negative reciprocal of the slope of line AB and b comes later.

Now, solve for b using the x and y values of point D, and plug that into the equation.

You should now have an equation for line DF and another equation for line AB. Now solve for the intercept of the two equations by setting them equal to one another and solving for x first and then plugging in x and finding y.

Here's an example.

A = (1, 2). B = (4, 8). D = (2, 5).

Line AB:

```
    (y - y1) = m*(x - x1)
    (1 - 4) = m*(2 - 8)
    -3 = m*(-6)
    0.5 = m

    y = (0.5)*x + b
    2 = (0.5)*1 + b
    2 = (0.5) + b
    1.5 = b

y = 0.5*x + 1.5
```

Line DF:

```
    m = -(1/mAB)
    m = -(1/0.5)
    m = -2

    y = -2*x + b
    5 = -2*2 + b
    5 = -4 + b
    9 = b

y = -2*x + 9
```

Intersection of AB and DF (i.e. coordinates of point F)

```
Line DF: y = -2*x + 9
Line AB: y = 0.5*x + 1.5

    -2*x + 9 = 0.5*x + 1.5
    9 = 2.5*x + 1.5
    7.5 = 2.5*x
    x = 3

    y = -2*x + 9
    y = -2*3 + 9
    y = -6 + 9
    y = 3

F = (3, 3)
```

Comment: aight, now lets see if I can figure out how to implent this.  I can see a case where AB is a vertical line, and that would cause a devision by zero... I guess I'll just have to write a case where that just takes the Y value of A or B and the X value of D to find F.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified exactly where point F is along line DF, so there's no single answer. If you're just trying to find SOME point along a line perpendicular to line AB, from point D, then

```
F.x = D.x + (B.y - A.y)
F.y = D.y + (B.x - A.x)
```

will work.

Comment: F is on line AB, and line DF is perpendicular to AB. A, B, and D are all known points on a 2D plane. F is where AB and DF intersect, given that they are perpendicular.

Comment: It is unique - DF is the 'height' of the triangle ADB because AB and DF are perpendicular. The question isn't brilliantly worded, and would be much better with a diagram.